# Replacement of obsolete LC filter

Tags: passive-filter, emi-filtering

I want to replace an "ELK-E103FA" 3rd order LC low pass filter in a PCB  which is in the market from last 5-10 years, because this part is obsolete now and not available anywhere.

Problem:

I am not getting any filter which has center cut-off frequency of 500kHz or with 0.01uF Capacitor/50V/2A.

Also, there is no space in PCB so I can use bigger then 1207 package.

Questions:

1. First of all why do these types of filter does not mention the inductance value, only showing capacitance value?
2. Can I replace this component with a feed through capacitor, will it work? For example, [this part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/NFM31KC103R1H3L/4906111)
3. What will happen if I select a filter which has center cut off frequency higher than 10MHz? I know it will not filter the noise but will it affect the output?

I have searched for filters on my own, the problem is they are too big in size and the center cutoff frequency is also above 10MHz, of course I don't have space on the PCB so I cannot use bigger packages.

Comment: Where are your specs ? Source , ,load impedance, DC current, BW, stop band attenuation & all tolerances.!

Comment: I dont know the specs, it is very old design

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The specs are readily available.  You only need to concern yourself with overcurrent and self heating degradation and try to match the I max and LC components to achieve the attenuation you need. (Which is TBD!)

Comment: I have found a feed through capacitor with same specs, can I replace it with this filter?

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/NFM31KC103R1H3L/4906111?s=N4IgjCBcpgLFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRACYBmADgHYaQCA2ATifJcfAFZaOICVerFpdy7bpQAMIALoEADgBcoIAMpKATgEsAdgHMQAXwJgmCEMkjps%2BIqRDVKtMJTmKVkdVr2GT4FmpOaEtUTFwCYkgyGXkQZVUNHQNjQSlYYKQw20iHMCkCqQACBQAxd3jPEABVXW0lAHkUAFkcNCwAV00cVIowbm4LKxsI%2B2jwYoBBMSmKhK9a%2BqbW9q6e-wBaciGoLQ67KLJB2SNToA

Comment: Looks similar but I didn’t see attenuation plots